# How to apply a data template on the cells of a DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, wpfdatagrid, datatemplate

I want to display some structured data in a grid. It is not really table data (no homogeneous columns or rows) but it should be displayed in a grid style.
I'm already displaying this kind of data elsewhere in a different structure. I'm using MVVM and I have a ViewModel type for each data element and I already have data templates providing a UI for each of these ViewModel types.

My Idea was to put all my element view models into a data table, bind this data table to a DataGrid's ItemSource and apply my data templates to the cells. But I cannot get it to work. Can anyone tell me how to apply data templates to DataGrid entries? I would prefer a pure MVVM solution with no template selector or code behind code if possible.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please provide more context information. How do your view-models look like? What have you tried? What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: Take a look at DataGridTemplateColumn.

Comment: @dymanoid I'm not really sure how this would help you. I have the general problem to apply data templates to data grid cells. Or more general I want to display a dynamic structure of view models of mixed types in a grid like structure. I already have data templates for each view model type (from another part of the UI). The view models are basically wrappers for data elements plus metadata.

Comment: @Clemens DataGridTemplateColumn is not really helping because I have dynamic data with no classic column based structure.